# Quadtree with HashMap

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, quadtree

I am considering using a HashMap as the backing structure for a QuadTree. I believe I can use Morton sequencing to uniquely identify each square of my area of interest. I know that my QuadTree will have a height of at most 16. From my calculations, that would be lead to a matrix of 65,536 x 65,536 which should give me at most 4,294,967,296 cells. Does anyone know if that is too many elements for a HashMap? I could always write up a QuadTree using a Tree but I thought that I could get better performance with a HashMap.

Morton sequence of height 1 == (2x2) == 4

Morton sequence of height 2 == (4x4) == 16

Morton sequence of height 3 == (8x8) == 64

Morton Sequencing example for a tree of max height 3.

[image]

Here is what I know:

- I will get data in lat/lon over a know rectangular area.
- The data will not completely cover the whole area and will likely be
  consolidated into chunks somewhere in that area. (worse case is data in all 4,294,967,296 cells)
- The resolution of the data ends up breaking down the area into 65k by 65k rectangle.
- I also know that I will likely get 10 to 1 queries to insert/update of
  the data.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "likely get 10 to 1 queries to insert/update of the data" ?  You mean 10x more lookups than inserts?

Comment: @Dave yes, I believe that to be true ATM.

Answer (score 2):

Hashmap is not a good idea.
There is a better solution, used in navigation systems:

Assign each Quadtree cell a letter: A (Left,upper), B(right, upper) , C and D.

Now you can adress each quad cell via a String:

ABACE: this identifies the cell in level 5. (A->B->A->C->E)
Search internet for details on that specific Quadtree coding.

Dont forgett: You decide the sub division rule (when to subdivide a cell into smaller ones), and that decides how many cells you get. The number you give is far to high.
It is only an theroetical calculation which reminds me 1:1 on Google Maps Quad tree.

Further it is import to know which type of Quadtree you need for your Application:

Point Quadtree, Region Quadtree (bounbding box), Line Quadtree.

If you know any existing Quadtree implementation in java. please post a comment, or edit this answer.

Further you cannot implement a one for all solution.
You have to know aproxmetly how many elements you will suport.
The theroretical maximum , which is not equal to the expected maximum, is not a good approach.

You have to know that because you must decide whether to store that in main memory, or on disk, this also influences the structure of the quadtree. The "ABCD" solution is suitable 
for dynamic loading from disk.

The google approach stores images in the quadtree, this is different from points you want to store, so i doubt that your calculation is realistic.

If you want to store all streets of all countries in the world, you can estimate that
number because the number of points are known (Either OpenStreetMap, TomTom (Teelatlas), or (Nokia Maps) Navteq.

If you realized that you have to store the quadtree on disk, then proably the size is open, and limited by only the disk space.

Answer (score 1):

I think that implementing a Quad **Tree** as a Tree will give you better results. Actually implementing such a big database in a HashMap is a bad idea anyways. Because if you have a lot of collisions, the performance of a HashMap decreases badly.

And apparently you know exactly how much data you have. In that case, a HashMap is totally redundant. A HashMap is meant for when you do not know how much data there is. But in this case, you know that every node of the tree has four elements. So why even bother using a HashMap.?

Also, your table is apparently at least 4GB large. On most systems, that just barely fits in your memory. And since there is also Java VM overhead, why do you store this in memory? It would be better to find a datastructure that works well on disks. One such datastructure for spatial data (which I assume you are having, since you are using a quad tree), is an [R-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree).

Comment: I actually don't know how much data I will have but I know the _most_ data I can have. If the HashMap didn't work out, I was thinking of both a QuadTree or a B-Tree.

Answer (score 1):

Whoa, we're getting a number of concepts here all at once. First of all, what are you trying to reach? Store a quad tree? A matrix of cells? Hash lookups?

If you want a quad tree, why use a hash map? You know there could be at most 4 child nodes to each node. A hash map is useful for an arbitrary number of key-value mappings where quick lookup is necessary. If you're only going to have 4, a hash might not even be important. Also, while you can nest maps, it's a bit unwieldy. You're better off using some data structure or writing your own.

Also, what are you trying to reach with the quad tree? Quickly looking up a cell in the matrix? Some coordinate mapping function might serve you much better there.

Finally, I'm not so much worried about that amount of nodes in a hash map, as I am by the amount purely on its own. 65536² cells would end up being 4 GiB of memory even at one byte per cell.

I think it would be best to pedal all the way back to the question "what is my goal with this data", then find out which data structures could help you with that (keepign requirements such as lookups in mind) while managing to fit it in memory.

Comment: OK, Starting from goal. I will get data in lat/lon over a know rectangular area. The data will not completely cover the whole area and will likely be consolidated into chunks somewhere in that area. The accuracy of the data ends up breaking down the the area into 65k by 65k rectangular. I also know that I will likely get 10 to 1 queries to insert/update of the data.

Comment: @Justin Depending on how much of the potential space might end up with data, this sounds like it would likely qualify as a sparse matrix. Some storage strategies are listed on the Wikipedia page for that data structure: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Storing_a_sparse_matrix

Comment: Yea, I saw sparse matrix and found a implementation in boost which uses a map as it's internal data structure. Which is one reason I thought of using a HashMap in Java.

Comment: @G_H Sparce matrix is bullshit, Quadtree is exactly the correct thing, it has sparce character

Comment: @AlexWien ... what? Look a sparse matrix is just a concept. It's actual storage may differ wildly from one implementation to the other. A quad tree could actually model a sparse matrix for all you know. Just depends on how you look at it or what your data means. NO data structure is "bullshit" under the right conditions.

Comment: @G_H In the Geo spatial domain, there are well known structures to handle his task. There is no need for an unspecific concept like Sparse Matrix, since there exists detailed concepts They are called geo spatial Index. Which typically is one of "quad tree, kd-tree". And a quad tree is no sparse matrix, neither kd-tree

Comment: @AlexWien Google "sparse matrix quadtree" and you'll see there's quite a bit of research regarding the representation of sparse matrices using exactly that data structure. When you visualize the asker's problem with his information that data will likely appear clustered in cells on a rectangular area, it's easy to see it as a sparse matrix. I just suggested one concept can be modeled by another and this can lead one to suitable solutions. But since your answer is probably closer to what he needs, I'll +1 that.

Comment: @G_H a matrix is the wrong concept, in a matrix all cells have the same size. Thats the reason why a quad tree was invented. Later sparse matrix application reaslized that they better use a quad tree, so both sparse apps and geo apps use quadtree. Its not the case that a geo App uses a sparse matrix. (Especially not for huge data)

Comment: I figured from his description that he did actually need all cells to be the same size. Without knowing the exact context in which he's gonna use this, it's sort of hard to tell. Feels to me like he wants to divide a rectangular area into fixed-size cells, hence a matrix. But thinking about it, this probably is not what he needs. So I was thinking of a solution to the wrong problem. You're quite right in that the quadtree would probably be more suitable to his initial problem.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely use directly linked nodes for both space and speed reasons.

With data this big I'd avoid Java altogether.  You'll be constantly at the mercy of the garbage collector.  Go for a language closer to the metal: C or C++, Pascal/Delphi, Ada, etc.

Put the four child pointers in an array so that you can refer to leaves as packed arrays of 2-bit indices (a nice reason to use Ada, which will let you define such things with no bit fiddling at all).  I guess this is Morton sequencing. I did not know that term.

This method of indexing children in itself is a reason to avoid Java.  Including a child array in a node class instance will cost you a pointer plus an array size field: 8 or 16 bytes per node that aren't needed in some other languages.  With 4 billion cells, that's a lot.

In fact you should do the math.  If you use implicit leaf cells, you still have 1 billion nodes to represent.  If you use 32-bit indices to reference them (to save memory vice 64-bit pointers), the minimum is 16 bytes per node.  Say node attributes are a mere 4 bytes.  Then you have 20 Gigabytes just for a full tree even with *none* of the Java overhead.

Better have a good budget for RAM.

Comment: In java you would not use a child array, simply use 4 fields: nw to se

Answer (score 0):

It is true that most typical quad-trees will simply use nodes with four child node pointers and traverse that, without any mention of hashmaps. However, it is also possible to write an efficient quadtree-like spatial indexing method that stores all its nodes in a big hashmap.

The benefit is that by using the Morton sequence (or another similarly generated value) as the key, you become able to retrieve nodes at any level with only one pointer dereference.

In "traditional" quadtree implementations we get cache misses due to repeated pointer dereferencing while looking up nodes, and this becomes the main bottleneck. So provided that the cost of encoding the coordinate space and getting a hash is lower than the cost of dereferencing the node pointers along the search path, such an implementation could be faster. Particularly if the map is very deep (having sparse locations requiring high precision).

You don't really need the Morton sequence, and you hardly need to think of it as a quadtree when doing this. A very simple example implementation:

In order to retrieve a quad of some level, use `{ x, y, level }` as the hashmap key, where x and y are quantized to that level. You only need to include the level in the key if you are storing several levels in the same map.

Whether this is still a quadtree is up for discussion, but the functionality is the same.